# Set Mercurial (Hg) Contact (or owner) via command line

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, hgrc

Is there a way to set the owner (contact field) via the hg or hgtk command line options?  I can bring up the repository configuration via:

```
>> hgtk repoconfig
```

What I want to do is something along the lines of:

```
[does not work] >> hgtk repoconfig set contact "Name of Contact"
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont't get your question. Who is the owner? Contact him for what reason? What does not work? Why hgtk?

Comment: mercurial doesn't generally let you edit your config files using the command line.  see http://twitter.com/#!/mpmselenic/status/8392230762

Comment: Oben - The owner is a field set in the hgrc file "contact=contact name".  It's used in our organization to track the owner of the Hg repository.

Comment: Ah, okay, the contact field in the hgrc. I was confused about mentioning hgtk in that context and I misinterpreted the `[does not work]` annotation. So, *Wooble* is right. Also, check [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4659135/151299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can only be done by editing ha hgrc file.  You can do it globally, for just your user account, or on a per-repo basis depending on which hgrc file you want to edit.

Here's the primary author of Mercurial's comment on a similar request: http://twitter.com/#!/mpmselenic/status/8392230762

More seriously the reason being that's there is no provably safe way to have a program read and write a configuration file that's also human readable in a safe way.  It really *feels* like there is but there's always a case that can catch you (duplicate entries? %include rules? illegally formatted to begin with).  It's all hassle and no gain.

### Update

If you know it's a brand new repo you can do that easily from the command line:

```
echo -e "[web]\ncontact = $CONTACT" >> $(hg root)/.hg/hgrc
```

It only starts getting unsafe if the hgrc already had a `[web]` section (or two, or one and two `%include` directives that *may* have them).

Comment: It has nothing to do with being afraid of changing a text file.  We have a process for automating creation of our repositories, and it would have been nice to script this into the process.  Instead, it's a manual step that can be forgotten or done wrong.

Comment: If you just created the repo you can be ham-fisted about it as shown in the update.